# Best Approach to Callbacks for Asynchronous Function Calls in a Conditional

Tags: node.js, callback, es6-promise

I would like to know what do you believe is the more elegant way to handle common code executed after a conditional synchronous function call.

For example, assume that there is a function that handles "identify and sort shapes from smallest to largest". Depending on the condition result (e.g. "is the shape to be searched for a triangle or a circle?"), one of two different asynchronous functions can be executed (assume in my example that for some reason the logic can't be combined into a single function):

1. Find all shapes that are a triangle
2. Find all shapes that are a circle

Based on the outcome of one of the two functions (depending on the condition), the subsequent section of code would have to be executed. That logic (call it "sort shapes") is assumed the same regardless whether the shape being searched for is a triangle or a circle.

If I used callbacks, I would separate the code after the calls to 1 and 2 above, into a separate dedicated "sort shapes" function that would be the same callback, like this:

```
function identifyAndSortShapes() {

if (searchingForShape === TRIANGLE)
   findTriangleShapes(sortShapes) // sortShapes is the common callback
else
   findCircleShapes(sortShapes)

... // The common code that would have been here is then moved to a
... // separate (callback) function sortShapes, due to the asynchronous
... // functions sharing the same callback logic
}

function findTriangleShapes(callback) {
... // Some asynchronous operation, e.g. DB query
callback()
}

function findCircleShapes(callback) {
... // Some asynchronous operation, e.g. DB query
callback()
}

function sortShapes() {
...
}
```

But is this practice (separating the code that I would have left within the `identifyAndSortShapes` function, into a separate `sortShapes` callback function) the right way to go? Or is there a more elegant way to handle this conditional asynchronous function call and then have the same callback code for both without having to create a separate function?

Apologies as my abstraction example might not be the best choice, but I think it shows what my current issue is. I believe this might be a basic conceptual one (on how to properly structure asynchronous code), so I look forward to your advice that could help me shine some light on this.

Comment: Is there a reason you don't want to switch to `async-await`? This way you wouldn't even need to pass the callback down the pipeline but rather you'd just return results from all these `findXXX` method and the `identify` function would continue on the same sorting path.

Comment: I agree with your recommendation, I gave the `async`/`await` option some consideration, and indeed it makes sense for a use case like this, where I say that the code at the bottom should not continue until the result of either one of the `find`calls is available. I will make `identifyAndSortShapes` an `async` function, and use `await` for the two other asynchronous functions, and the case is solved.